# Inferring when using tuple as inputs

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to infer the following? i.e. Where the parameter of the function is inferred from position 0 of the tuple *for each entry* of the array?

```
fn([
 [ objA, (val)=>{} ],
          ^^^ Inferred to same type as `objA`
 [ objB, (val)=>{} ],
          ^^^ Inferred to same type as `objB`
])
```

Comment: You want it to be the literal string `"objA"` or the value/type of `objA`?

Comment: What is `objA`?  Why would you want the type to be `"objA"` (is that a string literal type?  Or another type?  Or the type of whatever `objA` is?). Please consider providing a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE.

Comment: `objA` is just a generic placeholder for any type; does the specific type matter in this case?

Comment: @jcalz, I was contemplating providing an example- but the question is so general, I wasn't actually sure how I would even produce an example.

Comment: I mean, it should be easy enough for you to flesh out your code into some example where at least `objA` and `objB` are some actual *values* and where you describe what actual *type* you intend `\`objA\`` and `\`objB\`` to be (Note, types and values are different.  There's no type in your code named `objA`).  Like, my guess would be something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2aL8W) but I'm not sure.  Am I right/wrong with my guess or what?

Comment: Oh and if I'm am guessing right then it seems the TS compiler's not going to be clever enough to do that inference.  I would have thought the recent PR at [ms/TS#48538](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48538) would have improved this, but I guess not.  It can catch mistakes (see [here](https://tsplay.dev/mb0Vbw)) but it can't infer properly.

Comment: Yeah, that's the right idea. I didn't want to provide a specific type because I was hoping to get some insights on the core mechanism rather than just a solution (i.e. how to get it work regardless of what the type is). I was going in the same direction as you originally and ran into the same issue... but I wonder if there's a way to brute force it by setting a specific type per array position?

Comment: [Something like this, but ideally more elegant (and actually working)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/C4TwDgpgBBB2wCcQH0AqAeAGgPigXigG1MAaKACgDcBDAGwC4pMBKfXSgewEsATAXQDcAKCE8IAY1rUE0AGYBXWOOBcOsKLNjohUKAEEAHiR1QAQkZMBhC7oAiNqAFEHemAeBweAZxjwkadENsY11TNw9Yb19EFAxzYKtwzx84GIDrBLskyJS-WPR7TKdsqNT-DGcE7HJpAHMvRkI9MlMAfjJLdqhbLsdWvmZGTl5hIS54CARZanFoAHkAIwArVwBvE2pGWHkAWwXJ4V0Fxi9EcdrhAF8xiamZ+eWw9d1xRgWODloIalgroXE1KcoBxlnpGIsVvgoKsoJsoABGMjHKAAchRUEuwgBsCBIKWpnBjyhMNeGjoXmgmJEmnIhBMhDxzQoNForDwuFWlz4ISIeNMZCodDZHK5xgGwiAA)

Comment: Not sure why you opened a second question instead of editing this one, but I’ve closed this unless you can articulate why they should both be open